# How to loop music with SKAction?

Tags: ios, audio, sprite-kit, skaction, skscene

I want to loop my background music with an SKAction but the music stops after one row when I switch to an other scene. Is there a way to start the loop and keep playing it over different scenes?

Right now the code is placed in the init method of MyScene - is that the correct place? Maybe didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?

Here is what I've tried:

```
if (delegate.musicOn == YES && delegate.musicIsPlaying == NO) {

    SKAction *playMusic = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"loop.wav" waitForCompletion:YES];
    SKAction *loopMusic = [SKAction repeatActionForever:playMusic];
    [self runAction:loopMusic];

    delegate.musicIsPlaying = YES;


}
```

Comment: the sound action is no more than a quick convenient hack, for better audio control you are supposed to use AVAudioPlayer or personally I'd recommend a wrapper for both OpenAL and AVAudio, namely ObjectAL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't play background music over the scenes with using `SKAction`s. Use `AVAudioPlayer` instead:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"music" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSError *error;
AVAudioPlayer *gameSceneLoop = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath] error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error in audioPlayer: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
} else {
    gameSceneLoop.numberOfLoops = -1;
    [gameSceneLoop prepareToPlay];
    [gameSceneLoop play];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In iOS 9 use SKAudioNode for:

```
let backgroundMusic = SKAudioNode(fileNamed: "music.wav")
self.addChild(backgroundMusic)
```