# What is the code for my sound effect to loop

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am making a game for fun and I want to make my sound effect loop every time it ends, these are my codes so far.

```
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches{
        let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
        if atPoint(touchLocation).name == "startGame"{
            let gameScene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")!
            gameScene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            view?.presentScene(gameScene, transition: SKTransition.doorsOpenHorizontal(withDuration: TimeInterval(2)))
            self.run(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("mainmenu.wav", waitForCompletion: false))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't play background music over the scenes with using SKActions. Use AVAudioPlayer instead:

```
if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "mainmenu", ofType: "wav") {
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
    do {
        let player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        player.numberOfLoops = -1
        player.play()
    } catch {
        // catch error if necessary
    }
}
```

original post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23268462/6846532

Answer (score 1):

In gamescene, or any other scene you want the music to loop in use this

```
 let music  = SKAudioNode(fileNamed: "backgroundmusic.mp3")

  music.autoplayLooped = true
    addChild(music)
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would go with `AVAudioPlayer` or `SKAudioNode` because `playSoundFileNamed` turned being buggy in many SpriteKit releases, but I will show you how you can do it with actions:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("sound", waitForCompletion: true)))
    }
}
```